# My code is not looping through each row, instead it is printing the top row through my range

Tags: excel, vba

My final goal is to print my cells pipe delimited so in order to do so I am trying to print everything on each row into cell AB on each row. I am trying to loop through each row to do so however I am currently getting the top row of code repeated in all my rows instead of each row individually being printed.

```
Sub print_misc()
Dim cell As Range
Dim lastRow As Long
Sheets("1099-Misc_Form_Template").Select
lastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

For Each cell In Range("AB2:" & "AB" & lastRow)
cell.Value = Range("B2") & "|" & Range("C2") & "|" & Range("D2") & "|" & Range("E2") & "|" & Range("F2") & "|" & Range("G2") & "|" & Range("H2") & "|" & Range("I2") & "|" & Range("J2") & "|" & Range("L2") & "|" & Range("M2") & "|" & Range("N2") & "|" & Range("O2") & "|" & Range("P2") & "|" & Range("Q2") & "|" & Range("R2") & "|" & Range("S2") & "|" & Range("U2") & "|" & Range("V2") & "|" & Range("W2") & "|" & Range("X2") & "|" & Range("Y2") & "|" & Range("Z2") & "|" & Range("AA2")
Next
End Sub
```

Each cell in AB shows the result of the combined cells in that row (pipe delimited).

Current output:

[image]
Expected output:

[image]

Comment: Can you attach the current output and the expected output?

Comment: I have added pictures of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't incrementing the value of the row for each iteration of cell. You are point at row 2 for each one.

You also shouldn't use Select it is unnecessary just directly reference the sheet object.

```
Sub print_misc()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    dim iter as long
    with Sheets("1099-Misc_Form_Template")
        lastRow = .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
        iter = 2
        For Each cell In .Range("AB2:" & "AB" & lastRow)
            cell.Value = .Range("B" & iter) & "|" & .Range("C" & iter) & "|" & _
            .Range("D" & iter) & "|" & .Range("E" & iter) & "|" & _
            .Range("F" & iter) & "|" & .Range("G" & iter) & "|" & _
            .Range("H" & iter) & "|" & .Range("I" & iter) & "|" & _
            .Range("J" & iter) & "|" & .Range("L" & iter) & "|" & _
            .Range("M" & iter) & "|" & .Range("N" & iter) & "|" & _
            .Range("O" & iter) & "|" & .Range("P" & iter) & "|" & _
            .Range("Q" & iter) & "|" & .Range("R" & iter) & "|" & _
            .Range("S" & iter) & "|" & .Range("U" & iter) & "|" & _
            .Range("V" & iter) & "|" & .Range("W" & iter) & "|" & _
            .Range("X" & iter) & "|" & .Range("Y" & iter) & "|" & _
            .Range("Z" & iter) & "|" & .Range("AA" & iter)
            iter = iter + 1
         Next
     end with
End Sub
```